# Prevent GMSMarkers from Scaling on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I am using GMSMarkers on iOS with the Google Maps API. I have a GMSMarker with a PNG image and no matter my zoom level on the map view the GMSMarker keeps its size respective to the screen. If I zoom in it is 30 points across the screen, and if I am zoomed all the way out on the map it is still 30 points. **I do NOT want this to happen, I want the GMSMarker to stay small no matter what the zoom level is.** It would be preferable that I do not have to loop through all my GMSMarkers every time the camera zoom changes, as I will be eventually having 50-100 of them on the map.

*Is there anyway to keep the GMSMarker small no matter the zoom level on the GMSMapView?*

I am using Objective-C, but if someone can only give me help in Swift or even Java I can still make do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`GMSGroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_ground_overlay) to add an image to the map which scales along with the map. So instead of a fixed size in pixels like a `GMSMarker`, it stays a fixed size in metres.

Note that another difference is that a ground overlay also stays oriented with the map, ie if the map is rotated/tilted, the top of the image rotates to point north, instead of staying pointing to the top of the screen like a marker.